# Firefox back button middle click

Tags: 14.04, firefox, 64-bit, mouse

I used to middle click on the back button in firefox to open the last page in a new tab.

Unfortunately this stopped working for me on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

I tried to remove it via `sudo apt-get purge firefox` and reinstalled it, but nothing changed.

This is at my home computer. At the office I run the same Ubuntu version but x32 where this feature still works and I don't know why. It just stopped working from one moment to another and I don't remember what I could have done...
I also tried other mice...

It really annoys me, because I got used to this workflow.
Is there any chance this is a bug or something else you know?

Comment: Did it reopen the last closed page, or duplicate the current page?  I always right-clicked on a tab to reopen a closed tab, and middle-click on the refresh icon to duplicate the curent page in a new tab.

Comment: It reopened the last page I visited, the normal back button behaviour but in a new tab. Whatever... I managed to reset every setting in Firefox by accident and now it works again. I'm just wondering why `purge`ing firefox didn't remove my configurations...

Comment: Does purging firefox remove the user profile (~/.mozilla/firefox)?  That's what determines any non-standard behavior.  If you don't know about this, next time, try creating a new profile to test it using the command `firefox -ProfileManager`.

Comment: Is there a standard way to remove everything with a command or will it always sufficient to remove the appropriate folder in my home directory work after purging the package?

Comment: I only know how to delete it normally, which will always work; firefox will recreate it.  Using the Profile Manager allows you to create a second profile, and then you can choose which one to use, so you could have a basic profile to compare against the one you use normally, for example.  Or 2 profiles for 2 different tasks.

Comment: You're welcome.  And I learned a new shortcut, too, although I'm not totally sure how much I'd use it.